# Bind() - 3rd and further parameters?

Tags: wxpython

I'm struggling with the description of Bind()'s parameters given by ZetCode here: http://zetcode.com/wxpython/events as

```
Bind(event, handler, source=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, id2=wx.ID_ANY)
```

The first two are self-explanatory, of course. But what is 'source' in this context? id?

Regarding the latter, I certainly know about the GetId() method. But it works on ids set during control creation, not binding, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you use this already, without realising what it is.
for example, these are equivalent:

```
    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)

    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, source=self.timer)

    self.timer = wx.Timer(self,42)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, id=42)

    self.timer = wx.Timer(self,wx.NewId())
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, id=self.timer.GetId())
```

The `id=wx.ID_ANY, id2=wx.ID_ANY` simply allows you to assign a range of id's, where you would be responsible for checking the id, when the event occurs.
For example, I use this code for just such a reason.

```
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAutoTimeStamp, id=TIMESTAMP_OFF,id2=TIMESTAMP_COMMENT)
```

Where:

```
TIMESTAMP_OFF = wx.NewId()
TIMESTAMP_STD = wx.NewId()
TIMESTAMP_BOOKMARK = wx.NewId()
TIMESTAMP_COMMENT = wx.NewId()
```

Note that they could just as easily is 1,2,3 and 4
In which case, the above would be

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAutoTimeStamp, id=1,id2=4)
```

and:

```
def OnAutoTimeStamp(self,event):
    if self.autom.IsChecked(TIMESTAMP_OFF):
        self.auto_ts = ""
    elif self.autom.IsChecked(TIMESTAMP_STD):
        self.auto_ts = "S"
    elif self.autom.IsChecked(TIMESTAMP_BOOKMARK):
        self.auto_ts = "B"
    elif self.autom.IsChecked(TIMESTAMP_COMMENT):
        self.auto_ts = "A"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still need some more clarification. Unfortunately, I currently limit myself to using only the first two parameters, since that is sufficient to tie an event type to a specific handler. So, if I add a 'source', that will let the handler distinguish between, say, two different timers? What code would that take?

Comment: I mean, could you please provide sample code for OnTimer(), as well, since that is where the additional arguments are processed.

Comment: You're missing the point. It's really an either/or issue. You can hook the handler via the source, be that saying `self.timer` or by saying `source=self.timer` OR you can hook the handler via an `Id=` or a range of Id's `id1=x,id2=y` (where x,y is a range).

Comment: I surely am missing the point, and your help is greatly appreciated. My current question is - why would I use a third parameter (whether "source" or "id") at all? And the next question: if there is a demonstrated need for a third parameter, how do I handle that situation in the bound method?

Comment: Primarily, so that you can tie an event coming from a specific widget to a specific handler. If you have multiple buttons, you almost certainly want to tie `wx.EVT_BUTTON` for that button to its own handler, not  to some generic button handler, that then has to work out which button event occurred. In the case of using an `Id` I always use these when identifying a handler for a menu event. Each menu item is assigned an id, which I can then use to bind to a handler for that menu selection. It's choice of what is the easiest method in each circumstance to tie an event to a specific handler.